# Why would I need to compile/generate methods/code at runtime?

Tags: c#, ruby, reflection, lambda, monkeypatching

I'm interested in the theoretical aspect. What is the need in C# for using Codedom/Reflection or Lambda expressions/expression trees  for generating code at runtime in a typical day to day programing scenario? not in specialized cases

or in other languages like Ruby, why use monkeypatching for adding/modifying classes at runtime?

How this could be an advantage?

Comment: In my experience, it's mostly for specific things. Think of serialization libraries that generate serialization code using reflection and IL emitting, so you don't need to write and maintain that code manually. Expressions are useful for translating code to, say, SQL queries. Monkeypatching however allows you to replace/override existing functionality, and that can lead to a lot of confusion. Looks useful when writing test code though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, methods that generate methods are used *everywhere*.

For example, there are methods for generating setter and getter methods:

```
class Module
  def attr_reader(*attributes)
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      define_method(attribute) do instance_variable_get(:"@#{attribute}") end
    end
  end

  def attr_writer(*attributes)
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      define_method(:"#{attribute}=") do |value|
        instance_variable_set(:"@#{attribute}", value)
      end
    end
  end

  def attr_accessor(*attributes)
    attr_reader(*attributes)
    attr_writer(*attributes)
  end
end
```

When I call one of those methods like this:

```
attr_reader :bla
```

This will generate a method named `bla` that returns the value of the instance variable named `@bla`.

And

```
attr_writer :bla
```

will generate a method named `bla=` (naming the method with an equals sign at the end is the usual naming convention for setters in Ruby) which assigns its argument to the instance variable named `@bla`.

```
class Foo
  attr_reader   :foo,    :bar
  attr_writer   :baz,    :quux
  attr_accessor :gargle, :blarf
end
```

This will generate methods `foo`, `bar`, `baz=`, `quux=`, `gargle`, `gargle=`, `blarf`, `blarf=`.

Another example is the `ActiveRecord` ORM library for Ruby, which generates getter and setter methods as well as finder methods for models based on reflecting over the database schema at runtime.

`ActiveRecord` also has dynamic finder methods, that allow you to do something like `Person.find_by_name_and_age('John', 42)`. Of course, there are infinitely many combinations of database columns that one might want to search for, so it is impractical to generate all methods in advance. Instead, `ActiveRecord` installs a `method_missing` hook to intercept calls to non-existing methods starting with `find_by_`. However, once it has intercepted a method call, it generates a method of that name, under the assumption that the method may be called more often in the time and thus the dynamic interception can be side-stepped.

Generally speaking, this *Code Synthesis* is useful everywhere where *Code Generation* is useful, but with the significant advantage that

- it doesn't clutter up your source tree, because all generated "code" is ephemeral
- you are using the languages' own facilities to generate code, so it will (in some sense) be always correct, whereas with (simple textual) code generation, you will have to take care to generate syntactically valid code

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a couple of cases. One case is for performance reasons. e.g. when you a storing a compiled delegate that creates an object. Such as with some IoC frameworks. These compiled delegates tend to be slow to create but very fast to execute can offer a good performance improvement if the same delegate is called many times.

Another case I have come accross is in building dynamic filters with predicates and then serializing those filters in the database so that the user does not need to define them again.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to sacrifice full clean code to gain a lot of productivity and evolutivity.

For exemple, if you developped 1000 classes and create for each class a binary serializer. it is really easy to do it by reflection and code generation. It is less difficult to maintain unique dynamic code than a lot of static code. After full qualification of dynamic code the risk is really minimized.

fortunatly, generic cover a good part of this issue.

Generate msil at runtime is useless when you work on a little project.

Another consideration is for horizontal developpement (utilities/helpers) non dependant to direct business developpement.